# How do I select all list items within a navigation list in JQuery

Tags: jquery

So I was asked to use JQuery to select all list items (li) within an unordered list (ul) with the class of 'nav'. I tried a few different orders but was asked to recheck my work. Here was my last attempt.

```
$(".nav li ul");
```

Comment: You asked this question yesterday.

Comment: -1 Dude! If that's the second time you ask the same question, then at least accept the other person's answer.  You manage to put even less effort into this question than the first one. Not cool.

Comment: How about instead of trial > error > post on Stack overflow, you read up on the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I didn't see the answers people left me until after I re-submitted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
$('ul.nav li');
```

`$('ul')` selects all `ul`.

`$('ul.nav')` selects `ul` with `class nav`

`$('ul.nav li');` selects all `li` within `ul` with `class nav`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this breakdown Tushar. This is helpful and I'll use it as a basic reference point as I get more practice.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the ul that has the class "nav" then your selector is:

```
$("ul.nav li")
```

Alternatively, if the li's are the ones being assigned the class for some reason then your selector is:

```
$("ul li.nav")
```

Remember a space between identifiers in the selector will indicate a "descendent of" instead of the element itself.

Comment: "Remember a space between identifiers in the selector will indicate a "descendent of" instead of the element itself."

Thanks for that tip. That will go along way.